# Sending custom status codes from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda@Edge function set up in AWS that checks incoming requests for a given cookie and rejects the request if it's not present, or if it is present it modifies the request for another operation. So far the code works correctly in that the request is 'rejected' if the cookie isn't present, and passes if it is present, but the response I am getting from the Lambda is a 502 which isn't really appropriate for what I'm trying to achieve. Abbreviated code below:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
  const requestHeaders = request.headers;

  const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;

  // Perform cookie check
  const downloadCookie = 'download-cookie=true';
  let downloadCookieFound = false;

  if (requestHeaders.cookie) {    
    for (let i = 0; i < requestHeaders.cookie.length; i++) {
      if (requestHeaders.cookie[i].value.indexOf(downloadCookie) >= 0) {
        downloadCookieFound = true;
        break;
      }   
    }
  }

  // Reject if cookie not present
  if (!downloadCookieFound) callback(null, request);

  // I have tried this as well but it doesn't seem to work
  // if (!downloadCookieFound) callback(null, { statusCode: 403, body: 'Cookie missing' };

  // Perform other operations
  // ...

  //Return modified response
  callback(null, response);
};
```

How do I get the Lambda to return a 403 response instead of this 502:

```
502 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
The Lambda function returned invalid JSON: The JSON output must be an object type. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
```

Comment: What is `response`, log it before returning it and check if it matches the (json) structure expected. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html

Comment: I'm not sure if `response` is the issue, as the Lambda does what it's supposed to do if the cookie check passes.

Comment: *The Lambda function returned invalid JSON: The JSON output must be an object type.*

Comment: I see what you mean, although it was `request` that was being returned on a cookie check fail, rather than `response`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with luk2302's aid - change the line:

`if (!downloadCookieFound) callback(null, request);`

To:

`if (!downloadCookieFound) callback(null, { status: '403' });`

Other information can be added to the returned object if desired.